# How to change the default media player on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have a jail broken iPhone and I want to change the default media player from "music" to "pandora downloader". I am thinking the only way to do this would be with I file? The main thing I want is to have pandora downloader play anytime I hit the play button.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can do this without a jailbreak solution.  Basically the applications decide for themselves which file types are to be include "open with" dialogs and the applications don't always even include the open with feature.  

There is probably a plist settings file you can edit somewhere (if you're jailbroken and have access to it) with this info or even a cydia app to do it for you.  But ot sounds like you're asking for more than just changing the default player.  You want the built-in music app to actually switch over to pandora when you hit the play button?

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to make Pandora Downloader the default music app on iPhone (even jailbroken). There is a way to make Spotify the default music player ([see here](http://modmyi.com/content/8978-spotiplay-makes-spotify-your-default-ios-music-player.html)), but all that tweak does is change the little icon in the multitasking bar. When pressing play the music app still plays. While maybe that is a technical issue, there is also the functional problem of what the phone should do when the button is pressed. Should it play a random song? The first song in a playlist? It's unclear.